# Use normal es6 classes with NestJS and access any service

Tags: nestjs

When I have a nestjs app, everything is seperated into modules, controllers and services. But what I am actually looking for, is a way to instantiate as many classes of a certain type which then have access to a modules service for example.

I want to "spawn" classes on the go to act like a worker, executing tasks on repeat. Is this even possible with NestJS or cant I use normal classes to interact with NestJS services?

For example ModuleA has ServiceA,
serviceA created a bunch of objects of SampleClass which have access to ServiceA methods.

Comment: Why would the instances of `SampleClass` that `ServiceA` instantiates have access to `ServiceA` instance methods?

Comment: cause I want to have SampleClasses do not be affected by any asynchronous delays of serviceA